# Emacs on Sonoma: "WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate..."

Tags: emacs, sonoma

When starting Emacs on the command line like so:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs ...
```

it prints this warning:

```
WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
```

This started after upgrading macOS to Sonoma 14.0. How can I fix this?

I am using this Emacs version:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --version
GNU Emacs 28.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade [Emacs](https://emacsformacosx.com/) to 29.1 or above. This stops the warning.

**Note:** I downloaded `Emacs<version>-universal.dmg` from their [website](https://emacsformacosx.com/). I have not tested the `homebrew` version.

Comment: I'm on Emacs 29.1 via homebrew's emacs-plus@29 formula.  This didn't solve it for me

Comment: @FrankHenard I downloaded `Emacs<version>-universal.dmg` from: https://emacsformacosx.com/ . I have not tested the homebrew version.